# Change Max http thread count jboss AS6.1.0.Final

Tags: java, http, jboss6.x, httpconnection

I want to know where can I increase the `Max` `thread` count in `Jboss AS 6.1.0.Final`.
I surf through google but can not find exact answer and the files and locations mentioned there is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is done with the [Tomcat Executor](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/executor.html). You can read the details in [Thread Pool Configuration in AS 6.x](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ThreadPoolConfiguration).

A standalone descriptor may be written, whose name is, or ends with, "jboss-threads.xml".  The format of such a descriptor will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<threads xmlns="urn:jboss:threads:2.0">  
    <thread-factory name="MyThreadFactory" thread-name-pattern="My Thread %t">  
        <thread-group name="MyThreadGroup"/>  
    </thread-factory>  

    <!-- This is the Executor instance -->  
    <thread-factory-executor name="MyExecutor">  
        <thread-factory name="MyThreadFactory"/>  
        <max-threads count="100" per-cpu="100"/>  
    </thread-factory-executor>  
</threads>
```

---

ALTERNATIVELY: You can include it in a Microcontainer Deployment.

Due to the way that the Microcontainer processes XML deployments, it is possible to include your threads descriptor in the midst of a regular POJO deployment, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0">  
    <!-- JBossMC elements here -->  
    <threads xmlns="urn:jboss:threads:2.0">  
        <thread-factory name="MyThreadFactory" thread-name-pattern="My Thread %t">  
            <thread-group name="MyThreadGroup"/>  
        </thread-factory>  

        <!-- This is the Executor instance -->  
        <thread-factory-executor name="MyExecutor">  
            <thread-factory name="MyThreadFactory"/>  
            <max-threads count="100" per-cpu="100"/>  
        </thread-factory-executor>  
    </threads>  
</deployment>
```

Comment: this means that there is no direct place to modify like in other previous versions?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking for a JBoss config file like in AS 5?

Comment: I am lost with the term Standalone and MicroContainer. I am new to Jboss. Can you please elaborate more? Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is this, the Standalone is just for you app.  So that is probably what you want.  Have you considered upgrading to JBoss AS 7?  If this does not solve your issue/concern, can you please expound on your description in your initial question? This will also be a help and benefit for other readers.

Comment: Yes, I just need to deploy EAR. So I want to configure the server to handle maximum traffic. I can not go to AS7 as it is company decision to use AS6.

Comment: OK, but so far nothing helped me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot access this url due to company proxy settings. Chat URLs are blocked by proxy. Basically I need the same thing like this https://community.jboss.org/message/596832

Comment: Well before implement your suggestion. I want to know isn't there a direct file to modify like in previous versions? refer this url https://community.jboss.org/thread/199845  it has <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
            connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="300" /> I need something like this.

Comment: That thread refers to JBoss AS 7. The code you listed would work in JBoss AS 4.x but not in 5.x or 6.x.  You need the tomcat executor as described above. You can try to modify your `server.xml` but I don't think it will work.

Comment: That's what. I want to know how to do it in AS6. OK, I will try your method and update this. But Still if somebody can help me with a direct xml modification ??

Comment: The thread community.jboss.org/thread/199845 is for someone on JBoss AS 7.x.  The solution I provided is for JBoss AS 6.x.